# Can I do math on items inside 2 JComboBoxes?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

So I have two `JComboBox`es, and what I am trying to do is be able to compare the value in one, with the value in the second and then figure out the difference or the total. I want to be able to input a time in the first box (let's say `8:00 A.M`) and then I want to be able to input `5:00 P.M` in the second box, and have it display `9`.

Is there a way to do this?

I don't have any working code, just need to be steered in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `itemListener` on both the comboboxes and in those item listeners, check if there is something selected in other combobox...accordingly you can perform your calculations....